# How i can change name of parameters in url routers DRF?

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, router

How can I change the name of some parameters in url?
Like this //, but by default name of parameter is "pk"
I make request to `"api/product/1/rate/1/"` and get `{'product_pk': '1', 'pk': '1'}`.

I want to rename "pk" to "person_id".

How to make this?

```
from rest_framework_nested import routers


router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet)
rate_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'product', lookup='product')
rate_router.register(r'rate', RateViewSet, base_name='rate')
```

Comment: Where is NestedSimpleRouter defined?

Comment: Or how i can make PUT request to url "api/product/1/rate/" ? Because it required url like this "api/product/1/rate/<id>"

Answer (score 6):

You can control this by using `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg`. Here are the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes).

> - lookup_field - The model field that should be used to for performing    object lookup of individual model instances. Defaults to
>     'pk'. Note    that when using hyperlinked APIs you'll need to ensure
>     that both the    API views and the serializer classes set the lookup
>     fields if you    need to use a custom value.
> - lookup_url_kwarg - The URL keyword    argument that should be used for object lookup. The URL conf should    include a keyword argument
>     corresponding to this value. If unset this    defaults to using the
>     same value as lookup_field.

Answer (score 0):

This has been some time now. But ran into the same problem, and I thought that would be helpful to someone else.

In your `Viewset`, in the `ProductViewSet` case, add `lookup_url_kwarg = 'person_id'`.

Otherwise, the router will default to `'pk'` for `lookup_url_kwarg`.

This should solve the question. I hope it helps. :)